# Python File Not Found Error even though file is in same directory

Tags: python, file-not-found

I'm running a python code (filename- images.py) that reads-

```
    import gzip
    f = gzip.open('i1.gz','r')
```

But it is showing the FileNotFoundError.
My folder containing images.py looks like-

```
New Folder/
   images.py
   i1.gz
   (...Some other files...)
```

Comment: try using absolute path

Comment: Are are running the `images.py` from inside the folder `New Folder`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are not running the script from within the `New Folder`.
You can easily solve it by using the absolute path without hard-coding it:

```
from os import path
file_path = path.abspath(__file__) # full path of your script
dir_path = path.dirname(file_path) # full path of the directory of your script
zip_file_path = path.join(dir_path,'i1.gz') # absolute zip file path

# and now you can open it
f = gzip.open(zip_file_path,'r')
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the current working directory of the script by doing:

```py
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Then, compare this with your i1.gz **absolute path**. Then you should be able to see if there are any inconsistencies.

Answer (score 3):

The way I usually set working directory and work with files is as follow:

```
import os
pwd_path= os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
myfile = os.path.join(pwd_path, 'i1.gz')
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you run the script from the `New Folder`?

If you are in the folder, it should work:

```
c:\Data\Python\Projekty\Random\gzip_example>python load_gzip.py
```

but if you run the script from a parent folder with the folder name, it returned the error:

```
c:\Data\Python\Projekty\Random>python gzip_example\load_gzip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data\Python\Projekty\Random\gzip_example\load_gzip.py", line 2, in <module>
    f = gzip.open('file.gz', 'r')
  File "C:\Python\Python 3.8\lib\gzip.py", line 58, in open
    binary_file = GzipFile(filename, gz_mode, compresslevel)
  File "C:\Python\Python 3.8\lib\gzip.py", line 173, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.gz'
```